# Jpa inner tables

Tags: sql, jpa

I have two tables.First one is chain.The other one is group.I use this sql query

```
select id from chain where contextId=53
```

It returns 2 results like that

```
id
30
32
```

After that, I use this query

```
select count(id) from group where chain_id=30
```

It returns 46 record.Also I use this query

```
 select count(id) from group where chain_id=32
```

It returns 23 record.

How can i use this 3 query in a only one query?What i want to get 69 number in a one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine them with a sub-query like this:

`SELECT COUNT(id) 
  FROM group 
  WHERE chain_id IN 
    (SELECT id 
      FROM chain
      WHERE contextId=53)`